# Android cast MutableLiveData<MutableSet>> to LiveData<Set>>

Tags: android, kotlin, generics

I'm using variable shadowing and I have a something like

```
val selectedEntryIds: LiveData<Set<Long>>
    get() = _selectedProductIds

private val _selectedProductIds = MutableLiveData<MutableSet<Long>>(mutableSetOf())
```

However I get an error saying type mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the variance annotation `out` like this:

```
    val selectedEntryIds: LiveData<out Set<Long>>
        get() = _selectedProductIds
```

To tell the compiler that the LiveData will only produce such a set. Check:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#declaration-site-variance

Comment: Somehow completely slipped my head to just declare out on the LiveData type. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do the following

```
val selectedEntryIds: LiveData<Set<Long>>
    get() = _selectedProductIds as LiveData<Set<Long>>

private val _selectedProductIds = MutableLiveData<MutableSet<Long>>(mutableSetOf())
```

as to cast the `MutableLiveData<..>` into a regular `LiveData<..>` object.

Comment: This works however does raise an unchecked cast warning